# How to query-replace after a given character in a string?

Tags: sed, replace

How to replace all `/` by `.` only in the sentence after the `=` ?

For example, from this:

```
/buttress_unit/buttress_top/buttress_i_ps_but_cio_m1_i_but_m1_tx_wrapper_m1_pref_fifo_array_29__stream_id_3_0 = buttress_unit/buttress_top/buttress/i_ps_but_cio_m1/
```

I want to do this:

```
/buttress_unit/buttress_top/buttress_i_ps_but_cio_m1_i_but_m1_tx_wrapper_m1_pref_fifo_array_29__stream_id_3_0 = buttress_unit.buttress_top.buttress.i_ps_but_cio_m1.
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
sed ':label
  s|\(=.*\)/|\1.|
  t label
'
```

The `s` substitute looks for `=` followed by anything ending with `/`.  The capture with the parentheses excludes the final `/`. The replacement string copies the capture, and adds a dot. However, you cannot just add a `g` to do this globally, as sed wont look a 2nd time at the chars it has already matched. So you add a loop with a conditional *goto* (to avoid an infinite loop). `t` means goto the label `label` if the previous commands made a change to the line.